# Set up a newsletter system for my site

Tags: php, cpanel

I would like to filter my registered users db, check the ones who suscribed to the newsletter and send an HTML type email.

Are there some scripts out there for this? A cPanel feature maybe? Or do i have to write this with a php script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say don't bother, it's not worth the hassle of setup, maintaining a clean IP, and achieving high deliverability. Plus, the reporting is far more sophisticated than you would be able to achieve in building something yourself.

Use something like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) or [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/), both excellent services that have free plans or free trials.

As for the subscription, i would let the service handle it by using their forms on your website. If you really need to be able to see the status of the subscribers, then both have APIs that will let you grab the info to display in your application.

Comment: +1 - Don't underestimate the hurdle of deliverability. In most cases, it's better to let someone else handle newsletter campaigns.

Comment: Ok that brings a lot of clarity to my mind :D. I will take a look at this sites (and their apis). Thanks anthonyg

Comment: I would also suggest, that you look at Google App Engine. http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html With it is also possible sending out e-mails, also in bigger amounts.

Comment: @Hernantz - You can probably find extensions for some of the more popular CMS's like Wordpress, Joomla, and Drupal that interact with the mail services' APIs rather than having to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.openemm.org

- Easy to use
- Open Source version
- Active development

Answer (score 1):

I have used jangomail, constant contact, and mailchimp.  The best solution i have found is intersprire newsletter manager.  The beauty of their service is that you can own the software and install it on your own server.  Then you can use outside smtp services or setup other SMTP servers to send your emails.

SMPT.com is far cheaper than using mailchimp, ConstantContact or much of the other newsletter providers.  With the combination of using SMTP.com and Interspire you will save quite a bit of money.

Plus for riskier campaigns where you fear you will get blacklisted you can setup numerous STMP servers on cheap hosting accounts and send 500-2k emails a day, monitoring your smtp server to see if it gets blacklisted.

Comment: Most web hosts don't like their users sending out bulk emails precisely because there are users who do this sort of thing that will get their entire netblock blacklist. Then when their legitimate users try to send transactional emails to users, they end up in the user's spam box or just getting bounced back. I would strongly recommend using a MailChimp-type service for the "riskier" campaigns, just because they have the capability to tell you beforehand whether it will cause problems. And they have the infrastructure in place to prevent/undo blacklisting.

Comment: Also, could you link to interprise newsletter manager? I'm not finding it on Google.

Comment: Here you go http://www.interspire.com/emailmarketer/?ga_campaign=branding&ga_adgroup=email+marketer]&ga_keyword=interspire%20email%20marketer&gclid=CKDuo4qQq6UCFQsGbAodxFmBYw.  Mailchimp is not a good choice unless you have double opt in subscribers.  Services like MC, CC, and others will not allow you to use purchased lists, scrubbed contacts, etc.  None of this is illegal, but it causes blacklisting on email servers.  These services go far beyond Can SPAM act rules because they protect their IP address.  Best bet used VPS accounts on multiple servers.  Thats how the pros do it.

Comment: Once you have a totally clean list then you can use a different SMTP server for the actual mailing, Because at that point you will know that the list members are not going to mark your messages as spam, and most of the unsubscibes will take place on your test hosted SMPT servers.

Comment: Those are good point about purchased lists. I've only ever used in-house opt-in lists.

Comment: I've used Interspire in the past, its featureset is good, and makes it a good choice if you want to host your own setup. However, the features are still behind those of Campaign Monitor or MailChimp. Deliverability will be a problem over time. Also, large lists will take a long time to send out (send too fast and you will affect deliverability); services like MailChimp and Campaign Monitor have a much better infrastructure for faster sends.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any scripts available to do this however, you could query your database to export the info you need in a txt file then use a service such as campaign monitor or Mailchimp (I've used both and both work great, Mailchimp however, has a free version if you are sending out low volumes of emails).

Comment: ok this external service is good to me, but how to handle the new suscribers and the ones that have unsuscribed? is there a way to update/sync the mailing db with my usrs db?

Comment: Both of these services handle unsubscribes for you. They also offer forms that you can implement on your site to allow users to subscribe directly to certain lists. or you can manually upload a list and they will automatically remove anyone that has unsubscribed/duplicate emails.